# Tracking users between sites using contact forms

Tags: tracking, cookie, forms

I have two websites; A and B. I have hyperlinked linked these sites via advertisement banners and have contact forms on both. When people contact me through Website B's Contact Form I believe they are actually visiting Site A first and then after clicking through to Site B they then click the contact form of Site B - but they actually, initially, came through Site A.

Is there a way that I can monitor which site they initially came from?

I feel like it can be done but can't figure out how to do this. I feel like it would be through tracking cookies (eg. via ClickMeter), Google's Tag Manager or somehow through the PHP Contact Form but can't quite yet understand how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at Google's help doc on setting up [cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en).

Comment: My "contact me" link has a "regarding" parameter that lets me know where they found the link to it: http://ostermiller.org/contact.pl?regarding=StackExchange  It won't help if people switch sites before finding the link though.

Comment: You could try http_referrer and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Analytics to do cross-domain tracking:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

The problem with using cookies is they are assigned to a particular domain and 
a user's browser may not be setup to store cookies, even if it were possible.

If you have a login system on both, then you might consider establishing SESSION data to store the login across domains.  All you have to do then is refer the user to the other site by appending a query string onto the referring link.  This way, their data goes along with it.  This may look something like this:  http://www.example.com/linkedpage.php?sessid=32189

Another way to do this is if both domains can use the same database, simply store user info on the database that both sites have access to.  This could be done through a hidden field on the form or by action when a link is clicked.  The problem there is having a script reliably fire off in the face of security on the user's system...so you'll want to do back-end scripting (like PHP, Java, or Python).

Answer (score -2):

You should use regarding in your contact form or you can use a hidden form named site and give the name in the input value.

Comment: There isn't much substance to this answer.